# SSRS #ERROR in Expression field that sum the total debits - credits

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

When I calculate the total Debits in SSRS I get #ERROR. Not sure why the logic should work.
Any ideas on how to get rid of the #ERROR?

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!strType.Value="CreditsAndDeposits",Fields!intDT.Value,0))
+SUM(IIF(Fields!strType.Value="Refunds",Fields!intDT.Value,0))
-SUM(IF(Fields!strType.Value="Rent_Tax",Fields!intDT.Value,0))
-SUM(IIF(Fields!strType.Value="Sales_Tax",Fields!intDT.Value,0))
-SUM(IIF(Fields!strType.Value="Cost_of_Insurance",Fields!intDT.Value,0))
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If you run it in Visual Studio, the Error List at the bottom will give you a vague idea of what the issue is. My guess is adding different data types if intDT is a decimal - then you'd use `CDEC(0)` to **C**onvert the zeroes to a **DEC**imal.

Comment: I cant use visual code due that it not on the remote computer RDS that report builder is stored on.

Comment: You can try converting the zeroes to decimal with `CDEC(0)` to fix the issue if the `intDT` isn't an integer.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I could use CDEC(0) in my example?

Comment: You use it like `=SUM(IIF(Fields!strType.Value="CreditsAndDeposits",Fields!intDT.Value,CDEC(0))) ... `

Comment: That gets rid of the error but it returns wrong values.